# check that debug info is already uploaded

Tags: sentry

I need to upload a dependency debug info (f.e: pdb file) which is updated not so often.
I do not want to do this manually when dependency is updated. So I want to write a script and include it into our app CI.
Dependency vendor provide us with all required binaries (dll, pdb, etc).
Due to my CI is triggered quite often I see 2 options:

1. Check that specified binary is already uploaded (by hash?).
2. Just trigger `sentry-cli upload-dif ...` each build in case `sentry-cli` is doing this check internally before each upload.

So. I have 3 questions:

1. Is there a way to make such a check (opt 1)?
2. Does `sentry-cli` do such check internally on every `upload-dif` (opt 2)?
3. Is there any better option which I do not see?

Thank you.